# Define name ec2 instance cloudify

Tags: cloudify

I'm using Cloudify (version 3.2.1) together with the AWS plugin, and want to set the name my instance in the Amazon cloud. But to upload the blueprint below:

```
...
node_templates:

  mysql_host:
    type: cloudify.aws.nodes.Instance
    properties:
      image_id: { get_input: image }
      instance_type: { get_input: size }
      name: my_ec2_instance
```

The error occurs:

```
Failed to validate blueprint wordpress-blueprint.yaml: mysql_host node 'name' property is not part of the derived type properties schem
```

If I retreat and line: name: my_ec2_instance, the upload occurs without errors.

How can I set the name of my instance on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

the name property is only available in Cloudify AWS Plugin v > 1.3.1, which is only supported in Cloudify 3.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

In AWS Plugin 1.3.1 you could set the name by setting it explicitly in the key_name key under the parameters property.

Please see [http://docs.getcloudify.org/3.3.1/plugins/aws/#cloudify-aws-nodes-instance] for more information.